# How to install RAD ver 8.0.3 on top of existing Eclipse 4.2.2

Tags: eclipse, websphere-8

I want to use IBM Rational Application Developer for WebSphere, and it comes with Eclipse version 3, which is very old and clunky.

Does anyone have experience getting RAD to work with a newer version of Eclipse (such as 4.2.2)?

All I found is [this page](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/wikis/home/wiki/Rational%20Installation%20Wiki/page/Install%20into%20an%20Existing%20Eclipse%20instance?lang=en#InstallintoanexistingEclipseinstance-linkRad4ws803), which describes how to run RAD on existing 3.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on another forum. The short answer is NO, I need to use RAD 9.0

from https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=479652

> it is not possible to install Rational Application Developer v8.x
>   into an existing Eclipse instance that is 4.2.2.
>   ... if you are interested you could try the Rational
>   Application Developer v9.0 beta, which is based on Eclipse 4.2.2:
>
> Announcement:
>   https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/wasdev/entry/article_announce_v85next_beta?lang=en

Comment: Update: A colleague showed me how to configure Eclipse 4.3 for Java EE to use the WebSphere server. I've kissed RAD goodbye forever.